# Pentaho-IVYDC and IVYBC Plugin

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio, dashboard-designer, ccc

I Installed IVYDC And IVYBC plugins through pentaho market place but it is not rendered properly in pentaho dashboard .. when i tried to create dashboard through pentaho cde dashboards i cant use these two plugins ..In the dashboard components panel these two plugins are not showing..how to use these components in pentaho dashboard [image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Pentaho and Ivy plugins do you use? You should see `Ivy IS` item in CDE's Components panel after installation of IVYDC. It work for me on Pentaho 7.0 and IVYDC 0.0.6. 
Is the any error in server log during installation?

Comment: Hi im getting server log error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I send a mail to Ivy support and this was the answer:

> IVYBC is not REQUIREJS ready. Be sure to unselect the REQUIREJS option
> in your dashboard settings and reload the page. The components should
> appearm

It worked to me.